# Is there a canonical way of passing options to a Go function?

Tags: go

I am writing a package that exposes this function:

```
func Marshal(input interface{}) ([]byte, error)
```

This is fine for the majority of situations, but I also want to prove another function if there are extra options:

```
type MarshalOptions struct {
    OnlyStdClass bool
}
```

My first thought is to create another function:

```
func MarshalWithOptions(input interface{}, options MarshalOptions) ([]byte, error)
```

Is this the recommended way of doing this? Is there a standard naming convention for function that also provide a more specific version with options?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625363/go-constructor-type/41626014#41626014) might be relevant (particularly the additional links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a `*MarshalOptions`. The caller can then pass `nil` if they want the default behavior.

eg. 
`func Marshal(input interface{}, options *MarshalOptions) ([]byte, error)`

Comment: I think there is a few valid answer (which is why I asked the question in the first place) but I personally prefer this the most. I have posted an answer quite similar which I have settled on.

Answer (score 1):

One common way of doing that is to declare the function as variadic so that it accepts zero or more options. Assuming `Option` is your option type, you would declare it like this:

```
func Marshal(input interface{}, options ...Option) ([]byte, error)
```

Then, within the function, `options` has the type `[]Option`.

The function would then be called with zero or more `Option` arguments:

```
bytes, err := Marshal(input, Option1, Option2)
```

Or, if you have your options in a slice, you would call it like this:

```
bytes, err := Marshal(input, options...)
```

There are several references to this in the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec) (look for "variadic").

Comment: See [Self-referential functions and the design of options](https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2014/01/self-referential-functions-and-design.html) for a fleshed out example of this approach.

Comment: See also "Do not fear first class functions" by Dave Cheney (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5buaPyJ0XeQ)

Answer (score 0):

I found this to the be the best balance between explicit and simplicity:

```
type MarshalOptions struct {
    OnlyStdClass bool
}

// DefaultMarshalOptions will create a new instance of MarshalOptions with
// sensible defaults. See MarshalOptions for a full description of options.
func DefaultMarshalOptions() *MarshalOptions {
    options := new(MarshalOptions)
    options.OnlyStdClass = false

    return options
}

func Marshal(input interface{}, options *MarshalOptions) ([]byte, error) {
    // ...
}
```

Using the constructor pattern I can set reasonable defaults, without requiring that every option (especially if they may change) are explicitly set.

It's true that I could accept `nil`, but I don't because it makes it more explicit to read:

```
result := Marshal(123, DefaultMarshalOptions())
```